# Create service installer that uninstalls old version and auto starts and manages settings updates

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-installer

- Is there a simple way to create a service installer for visual studio 2010 that installs the service on a new machine and automatically starts this service.
- If a previous version of the service is installed it must stop this old version of the service uninstall it and install the new version BUT KEEP OLD Settings unless new settings never existed on the old version - i.e don't overwrite old settings but allow new settings
- is there a method to prompt the user for some information in a professional looking popup screen during the install ?
- Is there a way to roll back the installation if any of the installation routine fails?

thanks
damo

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you split it up in smaller questions (which you kind of already did) and search the web for each of them, you'll see there's plenty of information you can find. Summarize it for yourself and feel free to ask a question about a specific issue to which you can't find an existing answer. Also, your questions are full of terms that need further definition. What is a simple way? How do you store your settings? What makes a popup screen look professional? How does a user start the installation? What exactly do you want to roll back? And overall: what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use normal setup projects in visual studio you can combine the following functionalities:

- To create a service installer for a particular service follow these guidelines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf.aspx
- The setup project + service installer normally handles this, if not, create a custom action http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.80).aspx to achieve this. As long as you know the service name you can issue a stop command through ServiceController http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop.aspx
- Yes, use the normal dialog boxes available on the setup project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18834/Create-custom-dialogs-for-use-in-your-Visual-Studi
- The Setup project automatically handles this. Beware that you do custom actions implement the correctly to they can handle the rollback.